# Unreal Engine 4.18.2 "no default constructor exists for class "UUserWidget""

Tags: c++, constructor, widget, unreal-engine4

I have experienced a strange issue writing the constructor of UUserWidget-inherited class. The problem appears only (checked in several other) in this class. Code:
[.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2OH9.png)    [.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqH2p.png)    [UserWidget.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wlft.png)    [CompilingResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfWFh.png)

Comment: Sometimes your classes should be `DefaultConstructible`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - the same result

Comment: Do you get a compiler error? It's not quite clear what is your problem here. Maybe you can tell us what is the compiler yelling about.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry - just forgot to attach this picture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add this to your base class (UUserWidget):

```
UUserWidget();
```

That's because there is no default constructor for this class. The default constructor is one which takes no parameters.

Comment: There already is a constructor `UUserWidget(const FObjectInitializer &ObjectInitializer);` why might it not be a default constructor?

Comment: Because the default constructor does not take any parameters, so     UUserWidget(const FObjectInitializer &ObjectInitializer);    can't be a default constructor.

Comment: Similar result as with the previous constructor (I still don't know how might it help me - overloading shouldn't work in this case?)

Comment: Are you sure?, I'm almost sure that this is what causing your problem...     Your  UUserWidget class should be like:    public: UUserWidget();    and then    UUserWidget(const FObjectInitializer &ObjectInitializer);

Comment: I think that i did it wrong last time. Now there is still a compilation problem, but different: [Result](https://prnt.sc/i37o8j) [UserWidget.h](https://prnt.sc/i37o8j)

Comment: You've got a linkage error, most of them caused from including the classes incorrectly, this isn't about the constructors anymore.

Comment: Ok I have solved the issue. [.cpp](http://prntscr.com/i38hbc) Nothing else was needed. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @Sheim This is more of a specific Unreal Engine issue. You don't want to be adding code to the engine (as stated before). Essentially the difference is, If you look at Actor for example, it has a default () constructor. Whereas the UUserWidget does not. So you will need to just ensure you use the FObjectInitializer constructor instead. Should do the same job. Perhaps this is an oversight of Unreal Engine during their upgrade to allowing empty constructors. ```MyWidget::Mywidget(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer) : UUserWidget(ObjectInitializer){```

Answer (score 2):

add default constructor "UUserWidget();"

Answer (score 0):

For others finding this and being none the wiser, as Op just says "fixed it in CPP". Its almost certainly due to missing the following include:

```
#include "Blueprint/UserWidget.h"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).